# Scipy stats.rv_continuous to find MLE from 2-dimensional data

Tags: python, scipy

Referring to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52207964/fitting-data-with-a-custom-distribution-using-scipy-stats), I would like to find the MLE of `alpha` and `lam`, given the following PDF

```
import scipy.stats as st
import numpy as np

class Weib(st.rv_continuous):

    def _pdf(self, data, alpha, lam):
        t = data[0]
        delta = data[1]
        fx = (alpha * lam * (t**(alpha-1)))**(delta) * np.exp(-lam * (t**alpha))
        return fx

    def _argcheck(self, alpha, lam):
        a = alpha > 0
        l = lam > 0 
        return (a & l)
```

And I tried

```
Weib_inst = Weib(name='Weib')
Samples = Weib_inst.rvs(alpha=1, lam=3, size = 1000)
```

And it says

```
'float' object is not subscriptable
```

`Weib_inst._fitstart([[1,2],[2,4]])` also returns the same error message.

It seems this occurs because the data is not 1-dimensional, but I cannot find the way to bypass this.

Any help might be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to define `_fitstart` in your subclass. The framework assumes univariate distributions, however.